# What happens if two ships come out of hyperspace at the exact same time and place?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, hyperspace

When ships come out of hyperspace, it looks like they just "blipped" out of nowhere.

I know it's not very likely, but what happens if two ships accidentally come out of hyperspace at the same place and time?

Would they fuse into each other or destroy each other in an explosion (or maybe the former followed by the latter?)

Or is there some aspect of hyperspace travel that makes such a scenario  completely impossible?

Related: [Could you destroy the Death Star by having a ship come out of hyperspace in the middle of it?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/138226/64504)

Comment: Are Legends answers OK or do you only want an answer that can be verified in current Disney canon?

Comment: @Hypnosifl Legends answers are OK.

Comment: Your second question could be a duplicate,  I think,  depending on how the answers to this one go.

Comment: @Adamant I realize that they may be considered duplicates.  But I also figure that it's somewhat different.  In this question both ships come out of hyperspace at the same time.  In the other,  one is already in normal space, and the other ship comes out in the middle of it.  And there we're taking about the Death Star which is *much* bigger than normal ships,  so it might change things a little bit.  I've always liked the idea of not asking too many things per individual question.

Comment: They get splinched. ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that'd end both their trips real quick.

Comment: The chances of this happening are like 2^267 709 : 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost precisely what occurs in the new (canon) Star Wars novel "[Tarkin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel))". An interdiction field is used to disrupt a hyperspace shipping lane and a bunch of ships drop out of hyperspace on top of each other. The results range from simple glancing impacts to two of the of larger ships becoming embedded in another.

That being said, none of the ships disappear in the traditional cloud of radiation, so the most likely answer to your question is that two ships don't appear to be able to *precisely occupy the same space in hyperspace*, any more than they can occupy it in realspace.

> Close to the Interdictors, ships began to appear where there had only
>   been star-filled space. Tarkin turned from the forward bay and
>   stumbled back to the data pit to study the magnified view on one of
>   the screens. First to drop out of hyperspace was an outmoded,
>   saucer-shaped YT-1000 freighter, followed by two angular transports
>   and a lustrous space yacht. Then another freighter winked into
>   visibility, followed by two passenger vessels.
>
> Abruptly, Tarkin felt as if he’d been shoved toward the rear of the
>   bridge. With the interdiction field neutralized, the ships that had
>   been caught in the invisible web began to whirl out of control. Two of
>   the ships collided and drifted out of view. The magnification screen
>   showed the sublight engines of other ships flashing, but the ships
>   barely had a chance to flee or correct their spins when the field
>   re-initiated, capturing them once again. Tarkin spread his legs wide
>   in an effort to balance himself; then his eyes went wide as well as he
>   turned to face the viewports. Listing on its port side, an enormous
>   ship that more resembled something grown than built decanted,
>   broadsiding the Detainer CC-2200 before careening into a spin that
>   left its dorsal surface impaled on the Interdictor’s sloping bow.

Comment: When you say "two of the larger ships becoming embedded in another", are you referring to the passage about the "enormous ship ... careening into a spin that left its dorsal surface impaled on the Interdictor's sloping bow"? If so that sounds like ships that crash after emerging back into realspace at different positions, rather than emerging at the exact same place and hence being fused at the first moment they emerge, which is what I think Fiksdal was asking about.

Answer (score 5):

There is a one-to-one mapping between points in hyperspace and points in realspace, so the only way two bits of matter could emerge at the same point in realspace would be if they already occupied the same point in hyperspace immediately before that. In real space, obviously if two objects try to move into the same region they will crash against each other and the repulsive forces generated in the crash will keep their particles from occupying exactly the same points of space. These repulsive forces still seem to be operative for the internal matter of a ship in hyperspace (people on board ships in hyperspace can't pass through walls and floors of their ship for example), so I'd assume the same would be true for different ships in hyperspace; if you tried to move them into the same points in hyperspace, they'd just crash against each other.

The fact that there is such a one-to-one mapping is confirmed in the [*Millennium Falcon Owner's Workshop Manual*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon_Owner's_Workshop_Manual) which says on p. 54:

> it is understood that hyperspace is coterminous with realspace: each point in realspace is associated with a unique point in hyperspace, and adjacent points in realspace are adjacent in hyperspace.

As for ships crashing in hyperspace, I don't know of any depictions of this so that's a speculation, but it has at least been shown that ships can travel near one another in hyperspace, as in [this image](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/File:CitadelRescueFleet-CR.png) from *The Clone Wars* episode ["Citadel Rescue"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel_Rescue):

[image]

Also see this image from *The Force Awakens* which was posted in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/106900/22250):

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Does this mean ships can "bump" into each other while travelling through hyperspace? Interesting that even when the rebel fleet travelled together to the death star in RoTJ the other ships weren't visible from the Millennium Falcon.

Comment: I added some examples of ships being able to see one another in hyperspace.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish The Millennium Falcon has a faster hyperspace so maybe it was just ahead of the rebel fleet.

Comment: Not from the Star Wars POV, but in the Tom Baker story Dr Who story "Nightmare of Eden", the TARDIS arrives on the space liner Empress, which has become locked with the ship, the Hecate, after colliding with it on emerging from hyperspace. There was an unstable interface between the two ships and eventually the ships were brought apart.